# Logging in Play non-blocking?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, nonblocking

Is logging in Play non-blocking? Does it use some non-blocking IO API behind the scenes? Does it schedule on some other thread pool? I tried looking at the code but couldn't figure it out from there.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation just says it uses logback, so I'd assume it is blocking by default and you can use [`AsyncAppender` (note caveats)](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) if you want async logging.

Answer (score 4):

The logging is blocking by default, but you can configure Logback to use an AsyncAppender.  Note that AsyncAppender is lossy -- it will [discard debug messages if the queue is full](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/AsyncAppenderBase.html#getDiscardingThreshold()) for [better performance](https://plumbr.eu/blog/locking-and-logging).

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.6, it is blocking in DEV mode and async in production. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger